# Enable a button after another is clicked QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, software-design

I want to enable the access to two QPushButton which are in the same class after i've clicked on another QPushButton which is in a different class. Is this possible ? I have tried many things none haved functionned.

My code is as follows:

in Classe1.h:

```cpp
public slots:  
valider_push_button_is_pushed(); 

protected: 
QPushButton* valider_push_button;
```

in Class1.cpp:

```cpp
void Class1::valider_push_button_is_pushed()
{if (valider_push_button->isEnabled())  {close();}}
QObject::connect(this->valider_push_button, SIGNAL(CLICKED(bool)), 
this, SLOT(valider_push_button_is_pushed()));
```

in Class2.h :

```cpp
public slots: void valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed();
protected: QPushButton* Button1; QPushButton* Button2;
```

in Class2.cpp :

```cpp
Class2::void valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed() 
{Button1->setEnabled(true); Button2->setEnabled(true);}

QObject::connect(class1::valider_push_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
 this, SLOT(valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed()));
```

Comment: ***Is this possible ?*** Yes its not only possible but very easy. Emit a signal in your one widget connecting to a slot in the second widget which enables the button.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work, cause my buttons are protected. Or maybe my method isn't good

Comment: It does not matter that the buttons are protected.  I never directly access a button from a different widget or try to connect signals directly from buttons in different widgets. You should be connecting your signal and slot from widgets that contain the buttons.

Comment: I don't really understand..

Comment: In Class1 connect the clicked signal of the button to a signal emitted from Class1 buttonPressed. In Class2 create a void onButtonPressedInClass1() slot. Connect the signal from Class1 to Class2. Then in `void Class2::onButtonPressedInClass1() { mybutton->setEnabled(true);}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: like that ? 
in Classe1.h : `public slots:  valider_push_button_is_pushed();` 
`protected: QPushButton* valider_push_button;`

in Class1.cpp : `void Class1::valider_push_button_is_pushed()
 {if (valider_push_button->isEnabled())
 {close();}} 

QObject::connect(this->valider_push_button, SIGNAL(CLICKED(bool)), this, SLOT(valider_push_button_is_pushed()));`

Comment: in Class2.h : `public slots: void valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed(); protected: QPushButton* Button1; QPushButton* Button2;` in Class2.cpp : `Class2::void valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed() {Button1->setEnabled(true); Button2->setEnabled(true);} QObject::connect(class1::valider_push_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(valider_push_button_parametrage_is_pushed()));`

Comment: Why are you using enabled property of the button? A disabled button cannot be pushed. Are you thinking of a toggle button? Then the property to use is `checked`/`isChecked()`.

Comment: No, I have two windows which are opened when i click the associate button But theses buttons are disabled because my specifications say that theses two windows are inaccessible while an other button isn't clicked.

Comment: UP pleaseeeeeee

I have the following errors :
`"QPushButton* pop_up_create_parametrage::valider_push_button" is protected
     QPushButton* valider_push_button;`and `invalid use of non-static data member "pop_up_create_parametrage::valider_push_button"`
                  ^